# Adding a search form inside a div in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, genesis, search-form

I wanted to add a search form inside a div using the code bellow:

`printf( '<div class="entry"><p>%s</p>%s</div>', apply_filters( 'genesis_noposts_text', __( 'Try again below.', 'genesis' ) ), get_search_form() );`

But every time I add the `get_search_form()` it's generated before the div, like the following:

```
<form></form>
<div class="entry"></div>
```

The workaround I found was to split the code, but I wanted to know if there is a better solution that works properly.

```
remove_action( 'genesis_loop_else', 'genesis_do_noposts' );
add_action( 'genesis_loop_else', 'mytheme_do_noposts' );
function mytheme_do_noposts() {

    printf( '<div class="entry"><p>%s</p>', apply_filters( 'genesis_noposts_text', __( 'Try again below.', 'genesis' ) ) );

    printf( '%s</div>', get_search_form() );

}
```

---

[get_search_form documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use `get_search_form( false )`

`get_search_form()` will **output** the search form. Since you are trying to use use the result in a string context, you need the function to return the html in form of a string, which you are passing through `printf`.

The only parameter for `get_search_form` controls that behavior. By default it prints, but if you pass `false`, it will return the string that you need.

Answer (score 0):

To get search form as a string use `get_search_form( false )`.

Use can see document of this function [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/).